# Dynamic version of explode in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to write something similar to a `CASE STATEMENT` for Python, so my aim is to check whether the column is a list, and when `True` it should [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) that column.

Static Version:

```
docs = json.loads(docs)
docs = json_normalize(docs).explode("values")
```

Dynamic Version (How I started it, but then couldn't figure out how to finish it, or if it's even the right way to do it ):

```
x = (docs.applymap(type) == list).all()
for i in x:
    np.where(i == True,......)
```

Any guidance or tips will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In fact, explore with not list type columns is OK.

Comment: check after apply explore to every column, if the row num is not changed, then it's the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Figured out how to dynamically explode a column:

```
docs = json.loads(docs)
docs = json_normalize(docs)
x = (docs.applymap(type) == list).all()
y = x.index[x].tolist()
for i in y:
    docs = docs.explode(i)
print(docs)
```

This checks whether the column is a list, if its True, it iterates over the column names and explodes each one.